# Could not parse some characters: video.viewers.all.count| ans video.viewers_by_ip.all.count||intcomma

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How I can parse or sum two ManyToMany field in the template

```
<div class="">  <h6 class="card-text ml-2 p-2 bd-highlight" style="text-align: left; height: 1px; "><small class="text-muted ">{{ video.viewers.all.count + video.viewers_by_ip.all.count|intcomma }} views . </small></h6></div>
```

I tried to get this number by my view but I got this message

```
'list' object has no attribute 'viewers_by_ip'
```

my view

```
     profile = get_object_or_404(Account, username=request.user)

    if not profile.is_active:
        return render(request, 'personal/violated.html')
    users = [user for user in profile.following.all()]
    video = []
    for u in users:
        p = Account.objects.get(username=u)
        p_posts = p.video_set.all()
        video.append(p_posts)
    my_post = profile.account_video()
    video.append(my_post)
    if len(video):
        video = sorted(chain(*video), reverse=True, key=lambda video: video.created_date)

        video_viewers_ip = video.viewers_by_ip.all()
        video_viewers = video.viewers.all()
        video_views = len(list(chain(video_viewers_ip, video_viewers)))
```

Comment: Dont do this in a template. You should sum these in the *view*. A template should *not* contain business logic, only rendering logic.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried to make this in the view but I couldn't and I got this error `'list' object has no attribute 'viewers_by_ip'` I will update my question